# django admin send email to user

Tags: html, django

\admin.py

```
@admin.register(ParentsProfile)
class ParentsProfile(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Father_Email','Fathers_Firstname' , 'Fathers_Middle_Initial', 'Fathers_Lastname', 'Request')
    ordering = ('Request',)
    search_fields = ('Request',)
    actions = ['Send_Email','Send_Email_Disapproved']
    def Send_Email(self, request, queryset):
        html_content = "Your Registration has been approved.\n\nPlease use this %s as your username and %s as your password. \nYou may now start enrolling your student using this link https://...../Plogin_form/ \n\n\n REGISTRAR "
        for profile in queryset:
            send_mail(subject="Invite", message=html_content %(profile.Father_Email,profile.Parent_Password), from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                       recipient_list=[profile.Father_Email])  # use your email function here
    def Send_Email_Disapproved(self, request, queryset):
        # the below can be modified according to your application.
        # queryset will hold the instances of your model
        for profile in queryset:
            send_mail(subject="Invite", message="Our Apology,\n\n Your Registration has been Disapproved " + profile.Father_Email + "\n\n\n REGISTRAR" + "", from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                       recipient_list=[profile.Father_Email])
```

i have this code to send an email to user, how do i convert my html_content into HTML? so that i can design my message to user?

[image]
 it send to user gmail like this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render it with `django.template.loader.render_to_string`

You first need to store your template in your template folder, for example:

```
<!-- your_app/templates/my_template.html -->
<h1>hello, {{ user.first_name }}</h1>
```

Then in your code, change the `html_content` to

```
html_content = render_to_string('my_template.html', {
    'user': User.objects.get(username="some_username")
})
```

Doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string

Comment: html_content = render_to_string('my_template.html', {'foo': 'bar'}) where do you get this 'bar'?

Comment: the idea here is so that you can pass in context variables to your email, like username / first name etc, check updated answer

Comment: in your example, replace the first `%s` with `{{ user.username }}`, but the password you cannot fetch from the database as it would be hashed (and it's for good measure)